# Localhost:8000 keeps working after installing laravel-angular boilerplate project

Tags: php, angularjs, apache, laravel, service-worker

I installed `laravel-angular` project according to its documentation.
I run `php artisan serve` command which is supposed to run the server. That is what happened.

But then I wanted to kill this server because I think it messed up with my existing apache configuration. And I found it problematic because there is no command for killing it. All the resource in the internet says that all you have to do is to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to kill the process but I don't have it opened in my console any more.

It runs even after restarting my computer.

I removed the project sources from my disk hoping it will help. It didn't
Then I thought that probably artisan is running internal PHP dev server. I searched for it but this server also does not have any shutdown command - All you have to do is to <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> the proccess in console. It didn't help.

Okay so I though I will look for process id somewhere - using netstat or task manager in windows. I did not find anything listening on `:8000` port or any process that can be responsible for serving it.

Last try I had was to manually run `php -s localhost:8000` - seems like it succeded to start. I added some file to current directory and I was able to run it through `localhost:8000/filename.php`

However when I killed it (I see this process everywhere - in task manager, in netstat etc), `localhost:8000/filename.php` does not work anymore but localhost:8000 (which is then redirected to `localhost:8000/#/`) still works.
It looks like it's not the server running but some redirection is added to my machine.

I would like to resolve the problem - get rid of this and have my apache working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `laravel-angular` has service worker. Check in `Network` tab in Chrome shows that response for network requests came from service worker.

You may read more about them here - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/service-worker/introduction/